# Facebook connection loop internet explorer

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, loops, oauth

i'm developping a Facebook application with C# using Nathan Totten C# SDK and Facebook SDK.

I'm trying to get accesstoken from the Users by using many examples founded on SoF or others websites, and it works fine :

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
        form.setAttribute("action", 'FacebookLoginHandler.ashx');

        var field = document.createElement("input");
        field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
        field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
        form.appendChild(field);
        //Indicate the page where we are, to redirect here after data processing
        var field2 = document.createElement("input");
        field2.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        field2.setAttribute("name", "pageUrl");
        alert(window.location.href);
        field2.setAttribute("value", window.location.href);
        form.appendChild(field2);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    } else {
    }
});
```

In my FacebookLoginHandler, I put the informations in Session, and redirect on my page (field2).

Everything works on Chrome and Firefox. But on IE, I have a loop :

Go on my page => authResponseChange 'connected' => FacebookLoginHandler => redirect ont my page => authResponseChange 'connected' => FacebookLoginHandler, etc...

I really don't understand why, only on IE (except this is a bad browser :P), it doesn't work.

Comment: I found a code in php, but don't find the same in asp.net : `<?php
  header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');
?>`. Do somebody know ?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+how+to+send+http+response+header D’oh!